# Find out the sum of memory hogging process

Tags: windows-7, memory-management

As I'm always without memory on my PC I'd like to find out once for ever which is the most memory hogging program. The problem is that opening the task manager (I'm on Windows 7) doesn't seem to help.

In fact the task manager, for example, displays 10-15 instances of chrome*32.exe but I can't find a way of getting the sum of all these instances so I don't have any way to discover how much memory, for example, Chrome is hogging.

Is there a way to find out the SUM of all the instances of a program for every program, not just all the instances?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1, I swear Chrome does this on purpose so it looks like it uses less than Firefox (which has a single process) :) - Also, just for chome, browse to chrome://memory-redirect/ which will give you the total it is using.

Answer (score 2):

[Windows Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will do this.

This is a good tool for several other jobs as well, for instance it allows you to find which process is locking a file.

Also, as I said in my comment, you can browse to chrome://memory-redirect/ in chrome which will give you the stats just for chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just one little last question: is the field Private Bytes the one for memory usage??? thanks

Comment: Private Bytes and Working Set are both different memory metrics. There are several others not shown. You can toggle what metrics are shown in View>Select Columns

Comment: Thank you very much, I even found this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set which helped me understanding a little more. Great tool btw, thanks!

Comment: Excuse my question again but I was looking at Process Explorer and figured out that it is no more doing the supposed sum. Probably yesterday, due to excitement, I saw a non existing thing... When I click the +/- button I receive as sum the total only for the first value of the instance. Is there something that must be configured? Thanks and sorry